# Swift why does as? require AnyObject vs Any

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I'm getting a compiler error at the as?.  Type 'Type' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'.  Why would as? be requiring AnyObject?

```
func listForKey<Type>(key: String) -> [Type] {

    guard let fullList = (itemList as NSArray).valueForKey( key ) as? NSArray else {
        return [Type]()
    }

    // Filter out any values not matching the expected type such as if nil was used (value wasn't supplied)!
    let typeOnlyList = fullList.filter( {$0 as? Type != nil} )
    guard let foundList = typeOnlyList as? [Type] else {     // <== at as?, Compiler Error 'Type' does not conform to protocol AnyObject
        return [Type]()
    }

    return foundList
}
```

If I change the declaration to the following, it will compile:

```
func listForKey<Type:AnyObject>(key: String) -> [Type] {
```

However, it then won't work with String objects as Strings are of type any.   Any thoughts on what's going on?

[image]

I thought I had a potential solution after reading Anton's comment by casting to Any.  That resolved the compile time error, but now I get a runtime error (fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C):

```
extension NSArray {
    public func toSwiftArray<Type>() -> [Type] {
        // Filter out any values not matching the expected type such as nil
        let typeOnlyList : [AnyObject] = self.filter( {$0 is Type} )
        let typeOnlyAnyList : [Any] = typeOnlyList as [Any]                // <== Runtime error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
        guard let foundList : [Type] = typeOnlyAnyList as? [Type] else {
            return [Type]()
        }

        return foundList
    }
}
```

Why would casting from [AnyObject] to [Any] cause a runtime error?  I figured [Any] was the super set of [AnyObject].

Comment: try using the is keyword  - for example in the closure passed in the filter put {$0 is Type} also i would recommend using a single capital letter for a generic type as that is convention

Comment: I switched it over to {$0 is String} as it's more clear, but the problem is on the next line.  It's complaining about the as? on the following line

Comment: Wouldn't this always pass because  [Type] can't be a nil, but you are saying nil is a option

Comment: Good question: The underlying object has swift optionals as members.  Thus it's very possible for the NSArray to have NIL placeholder objects in it.  These placeholder object can't be converted to Type because they are nil.  So the filter makes sure to only includes objects in the final result that can be converted to Type.  Thus allowing us to get back from the NSArray into a valid swift [Type].

Comment: I believe it might be connected with the fact that `as?` is a dynamic cast and dynamic cast can be used only on classes because structs cannot use inheritance (you cannot cast between different struct types). `AnyObject` is the representation of class types in swift.

Comment: Usually, you can use as? with a type of Any.  I think @Anton Bronnikov is close to the answer.  What's odd is that when casing [AnyObject] to [Any] I get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this doesn't really answer the original question.  However, it is a workaround that gets the job done.  I still don't understand why the solution above doesn't work (especially the fatal error when casting from [AnyObject] to [Any]), but I took a different approach which works great:

```
extension NSArray {
    public func toSwiftArray<Type>() -> [Type] {
        var swiftArray = [Type]()

        for value in self {
            if let valueOfType = value as? Type {
                swiftArray.append( valueOfType )
            }
        }

        return swiftArray
    }

    public func toSwiftArray<Type>() -> ([Type], [Any]) {
        var swiftTypeArray = [Type]()
        var unknownTypeArray = [Any]()

        for value in self {
            if let valueOfType = value as? Type {
                swiftTypeArray.append( valueOfType )
            } else {
                unknownTypeArray.append( value )
            }
        }

        return (swiftTypeArray, unknownTypeArray)
    }
}
```

Not sure why I couldn't use .filter to do this, but this is a very straightforward solution to the problem, and it also allows for a version that returns a list of the values that couldn't be converted.  This is very handy routine for converting to NSArray with full type safety.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
guard let fullList = ... as? NSArray
```

... you declare your `fullList` variable to be `NSArray`.

Therefore `typeOnlyList` is also `NSArray` (it's a result of filtering of `fullList`).

`NSArray`'s elements are `AnyObject`'s (bridged from Objective-C).

Therefore, when you try to cast `typeOnlyList as? [Type]` Swift expects `Type` to conform to `AnyObject` protocol.

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense.  However, why does it work when I use String (instead of the generic Type)?  Is swift auto bridging to NSString?  It also works for other Any types such as Int.  Is there some protocol I can specify to allow it to accept objects that can be auto boxed?

Comment: I got it to compile by casting the self.filter result to [AnyObject] and then to [Any].  However, I get a runtime error on the cast to [Any]. very Interesting.

Comment: If you do `guard let foundList = typeOnlyList as? [String]` then `foundList` gets to be `[String]` that you can not return as `[Type]` in the end of the method.  I think the way for you is to change the signature of the method to `func listForKey<Type where Type: AnyObject>(key: String) -> [Type]` (note the where-clause).

Comment: Yep it works if I limit it to only be of AnyObject, but then it won't work for swift String objects as Strings in swift are value types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with `NSArray` in Swift, you will have to work with classes only because `NSArray` cannot hold anything else.

```
extension NSArray {
    public func toSwiftArray<Type: AnyObject>() -> [Type] {

        let typeOnlyList : NSArray = self.filter( {$0 is Type} )
        return typeOnlyList as! Array<Type>
    }
}

let nsArray: NSArray = [10, 20, "my-text"]
print("NSArray: \(nsArray)")

let swiftArray: [NSString] = nsArray.toSwiftArray()
print("Swift array: \(swiftArray)")
```

In short: use `NSString` instead of `String`. You can also convert `[NSString]` to `[String]` as the second step.

Comment: I should give a little more background on how this came up.  I'm using Key Value Coding in Swift on an @objc class with dynamic properties.  These properties are being set from JSON via ObjectMapper.  The class has String Optionals so if they aren't supplied by the JSON they are nil.  Then I use something like (itemList as NSArray).valueForKey( key ) to get a list of all items matching the key.  The items will all be of the same type, except those that are nil.  So I needed a safe way to get them back to a swift type such as String.

Comment: @TodCunningham Could you produce a minimum reproducible example? A  demo data in Obj-C and what you want to do with them in Swift?

Comment: Your code does work.  It's interesting as the only real difference is the as! vs as?.